# jQuery sequence of $.when.then() executions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute functions in a particular sequence, but I am running into issues when it comes to understanding `$.when()`.

```js
function x() {
  def = $.Deferred();
  $.when(def).then(console.log(def.state()));
}
x();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My understanding is that when `def` is resolved then the `console.log(def.state())` should execute. In other words, shouldn't I get nothing back when executing `x()` since `def` is `pending`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`then` expects a callback so you should create a wrap function:

```
function x() {
  def = $.Deferred();
  $.when(def).then(function(){
    console.log(def.state())
  });
}
x();
```

Comment: Explanation why might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First: you should resolve your `Deffered`. Second: you should pass a function to `then` method.

```js
function x() {
  def = $.Deferred().resolve();
  $.when(def).then(function () {
    console.log(def.state());
  });
}
x();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```